# how to set custom Y-labels in MPAndroid chart

Tags: android, charts

I use MPAndroid Chart to present some values in time (the performance of some users). The code prepared the chart data is:

```
            BarChart chart = (BarChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chart);

            ArrayList<BarEntry> enteries = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                enteries.add(new BarEntry(data[i].getValue(), i));
                labels.add(data[i].getName());
            }
            BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(enteries, "");

            int[] clr = new int[]{Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.rgb(0xff, 0xff, 0x00), Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK};
            dataSet.setColors(clr);
            chart.setData(new BarData(labels, dataSet));
            chart.animateY(500);
```

Values in 'data' are in 'seconds'. 
How can I show values both in Y-labels and above the bars in `hhhh:mm:ss` format, i.e. 1:40 (1 minute and 40 seconds) instead of 100. 
[image]

**EDIT1:**
I solved the problem of Y-Lables by defining a custom `YAxisValueFormatter`
class:

```
    public class MyYAxisValueFormatter implements YAxisValueFormatter{
        public MyYAxisValueFormatter () {
        }

        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, YAxis yAxis) {
            String yLabel="";
            int h=(int)(value/3600);
            int m=(int)((value%3600)/60);
            int s=(int)(value%60);
            if(h>0)
                yLabel=yLabel+Integer.toString(h)+":";
            if(m>0)
                yLabel=yLabel+Integer.toString(m)+":";
            yLabel=yLabel+Integer.toString(s);
            return yLabel;
        }
    }
```

but I couldn't find any way to change the format of the values above the bars yet!

Comment: Can you please point out where is 100 ? I not able to understand your comment. Please clarify.

Comment: it is just an example. ANother example is `10,000` which is shown as the first Y-label after zero, should be shown as`2:46:40`. It means instead of 10,000 seconds I wanna show `2:46:40` (2 hours, 46 minutes and 46 seconds)

Comment: What values you have in `data[i].getValue()`? Is it your `hhhh:mm:ss` format value?

Comment: data includes integer values. Please have a look at EDIT1.

Comment: Check `setValueFormatter` method of YAxis.

Comment: Hi Behy, can you post whole code. I have the same requirment. But I'm confused when you pass "i" while creating BarEntry list object. That is, 0,1,2,3,4... Then how did you fixed showing time as per your MyYAxisValueFormatter()?